# Aggregate over a column of strings Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have the following Spark dataframe:

```
column1|column2
A|"1"
A|"1"
A|"2"
B|"1"
```

and I would like to get the count of each distinct value grouped by column1. The expected output would be something like this:

```
column1|column2
A|"1:2,2:1"
B|"1:1"
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groupby `column1, column2` to count distinct values and then groupby again by `column1` and collect list of pairs `column2:count`. Something like this:

```
data = [("A", "1"), ("A", "1"),
        ("A", "2"), ("B", "1")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["column1", "column2"])

df.groupBy("column1", "column2").agg(count("*").alias("ct")) \
    .groupBy("column1") \
    .agg(collect_list(concat(col("column2"), lit(":"), col("ct"))).alias("result")) \
    .drop("column2", "ct")\
    .show()
```

Gives:

```
+-------+----------+
|column1|    result|
+-------+----------+
|      B|     [1:1]|
|      A|[1:2, 2:1]|
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way is grouping by column1 and column2:

`df2 = df.groupBy(df.column1, df.column2).count()`

so you'll get something like:

```
column1 | column2 | count 
A       | "1"     | 2 
A       | "2"     | 1 
B       | "1"     | 1
```

This will be the easiest way of working with the desired dataset. If you want your dataset, you can now concatenate `column2` and `count` and then group again by `column1` and concatenate the group elements.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Is there a way to do this directly using aggregations and sql functions? I can get the possible values of column 2 grouped by column A using: `df.groupby(["column1"]).agg(f.concat_ws(",", f.collect_set(df.column2)))` but I would like to add the count as well.